# How to read XML Elements and Child Elements and display data in HTML Table using php?

Tags: php, html, xml

i`m a newbie to php and javascript but i have a personal project that needs knowledge about these languages.

i have two xml files that i would like to read and display.

file 1 is a transaction file by a user and file 2 is a summary of transaction files and Total of all summary files (depending on how many transaction files user(s) created).

### Here is my file 1

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CmpOUT>
<TRX>
   <Version>3.0.19.82</Version>
   <DeviceProductName>Product</DeviceProductName>
   <DeviceSerialNumber>4C02890FD627</DeviceSerialNumber>
   <LocationName>Demo place</LocationName>
   <InputNumber>guest</InputNumber>
   <InputSubNumber></InputSubNumber>
   <OutputNumber></OutputNumber>
   <OutputSubNumber></OutputSubNumber>
   <TrxCode>1</TrxCode>
   <BagNumber>999999</BagNumber>
   <NoteJam>0</NoteJam>
   <TranAmount>35850.00</TranAmount>
   <DateTime>2016-12-03T16:17:42</DateTime>
   <TranCycle>2072</TranCycle>
   <ContainerCycle>64</ContainerCycle>
   <ContainerNumber></ContainerNumber>
   <TotalNumberOfNotes>0</TotalNumberOfNotes>
   <NoteCount>
      <Currency>ZAR</Currency>
      <Denomination>10.00</Denomination>
      <NumberOfNotes>10</NumberOfNotes>
   </NoteCount>
   <NoteCount>
      <Currency>ZAR</Currency>
      <Denomination>20.00</Denomination>
      <NumberOfNotes>20</NumberOfNotes>
   </NoteCount>
   <NoteCount>
      <Currency>ZAR</Currency>
      <Denomination>50.00</Denomination>
      <NumberOfNotes>11</NumberOfNotes>
   </NoteCount>
   <NoteCount>
      <Currency>ZAR</Currency>
      <Denomination>100.00</Denomination>
      <NumberOfNotes>198</NumberOfNotes>
   </NoteCount>
   <NoteCount>
      <Currency>ZAR</Currency>
      <Denomination>200.00</Denomination>
      <NumberOfNotes>75</NumberOfNotes>
   </NoteCount>
   <Reference>DemoUser</Reference>
   <ShiftReference></ShiftReference>
</TRX>
</CmpOUT>
```

---

---

My file 1 is a transaction file which has a number Elements/Nodes and Child Elements (14 Main Elements, 3 Child elements).

I would like to use PHP to read all these elements and display their data in HTML table content.

### Here is my file 2

```html
<EODSummary>
   <Summary>
      <Transaction>
         <Date>2017-01-06</Date>
         <Time>17:54:57</Time>
         <InputNumber>guest</InputNumber>
         <RefNo>TILL25</RefNo>
         <Amount>19620.00</Amount>
      </Transaction>
      <Transaction>
         <Date>2017-01-06</Date>
         <Time>17:56:06</Time>
         <InputNumber>guest</InputNumber>
         <RefNo>TLL28</RefNo>
         <Amount>300.00</Amount>
      </Transaction>
      <Transaction>
         <Date>2017-01-06</Date>
         <Time>17:56:54</Time>
         <InputNumber>guest</InputNumber>
         <RefNo>TILL09</RefNo>
         <Amount>4770.00</Amount>
      </Transaction>
      <Transaction>
         <Date>2017-01-06</Date>
         <Time>17:57:36</Time>
         <InputNumber>guest</InputNumber>
         <RefNo>TILL04</RefNo>
         <Amount>320.00</Amount>
      </Transaction>
      <Information>
         <EODNo>87</EODNo>
         <BagNumber>999999</BagNumber>
         <DeviceSerialNumber>4C02890FD627</DeviceSerialNumber>
         <ContainerNumber>014</ContainerNumber>
         <ContainerCycle>84</ContainerCycle>
         <Currency>ZAR</Currency>
         <Name>Demo Place</Name>
         <Date>2017-01-07</Date>
         <Time>07:19:16</Time>
         <Transactions>4</Transactions>
         <TotalValue>25010.00</TotalValue>
         <Denomination1>54</Denomination1>
         <Denomination2>76</Denomination2>
         <Denomination3>67</Denomination3>
         <Denomination4>98</Denomination4>
         <Denomination5>49</Denomination5>
      </Information>
   </Summary>
</EODSummary>
```

---

So basically, file 1 which is a transaction file belongs to the Summary file and transaction files are listed in Summary file and added up to give Total of all transactions.

This looks a bit complex to me the newbie in PHP but i hope you guys can understand.

Lastly i would like to Thank everyone on the site for allowing me to post and ask for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

In your index.php file:

```
 echo "<table>"; //create table in html
    $xmlstr = file_get_contents("relative/path/toyourXML/xml.xml"); //read the contents into the php variable
    $examples = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr); //Creating the Simple xml object
    echo "<tr> <td>".$examples->TRX->Version. "</td> </tr>";  //This will echo the version in a new table row and in a cell,any other data you can do in a similar fashion, just use -> to get there, and for more iterations use foreach
```

I hope this example can help you understand how to work with SimpleXML, duplicate board here: [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)